# Log into website with ASIHttpRequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have a website that i want to log into from my iphone in a iphone app i am making, i followed the documentation on ASIHttpRequests website but all i get from the response string is the html code for the login page , but i get a OK http code, Why is this happening?

Here is my code :

```
-(IBAction)fetchData:(id)sender 
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rssit.site90.com/login.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];

//Add finish or failed selector
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestLoginFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestLoginFailed:)];




}

- (void)requestLoginFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

NSString *yourResponse = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@", yourResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form on that page is doing a get, not a post. Your server is probably not expecting POST data, and is looking at query string params instead. Change to 
`[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rssit.site90.com/login.php?username=YOURUSERNAME&password=YOURPASSWORD"];`

and set the requestMethod to GET.

Comment: That did not work, Is there somthing in my php that i should have?